# Syntax for adding items to Observablecollection

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Public Dictionary defined as

```
public Dictionary<string, double> comboBoxSelections { get; set; }
```

and add items to it using

```
this.comboBoxSelections = new Dictionary<string, double>();
comboBoxSelections.Add(currItem, d);
```

I want to use this as an ItemsSource for a ComboBox in WPF so whenever comboBoxSelections is updated I see the updated items available for selection in the ComboBox. So I think perhaps I need to wrap this in an ObservableCollection as

```
public ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, double>> comboBoxSelections { get; set; }
this.comboBoxSelections = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, double>>();
```

What is the syntax for adding new Dictionary items to the ObservableCollection? Something like...

```
comboBoxSelections.Add(new Dictionary<string, double>(currItem, d));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<string,double>>` or `ObservableCollection<Tuple<string,double>>` then you can bind to these values in XAML.

Or you can use ObservableDictionary check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3818365/wpf-how-can-i-implement-an-observablecollectionk-t-with-a-key-like-a-dictio) and [there](http://drwpf.com/blog/2007/09/16/can-i-bind-my-itemscontrol-to-a-dictionary/).